# Opengl shader: if condition wrongly evaluated to false

Tags: qt, opengl, glsl, shader

I recently bought the "opengl shading language cookbook".
I'm trying to code one of the examples: specifically the reflection cubemap.

As it is now, my software crashes.

I could narrow down the issue to an if condition which is, supposidly, true, but the "false" part is seemingly executed (more details to come).

The goal is:

- draw a skybox.
- draw an object (a teapot), which reflects the skybox.

Development environment:
I tried on 2 PCs (work laptop and home-gaming rig) with QT5.6.0 and on my laptop PC with QT 5.3.0. QT 5.6.0 is the 32 bits version compiled with mingw, not sure about the 5.3.0 version.

Both PCs have an nvidia card. I won't go more into details as I do not think the problem lies there (unless identified otherwise in the answers).

I have removed the teapot drawcall.
I currently only draw the Skybox. Which means **the "DrawSkyBox" boolean uniform is always true.** This is important.

The vertex shader is where the problem lies (or at least the one that provokes the crash).
The code is here (this is the code/project from the book, not mine which is anyway a copy/paste):

```
#version 430

layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 VertexNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 VertexTexCoord;

out vec3 ReflectDir;

uniform bool DrawSkyBox;
uniform vec3 WorldCameraPosition;

uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelMatrix;
uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
    if( DrawSkyBox ) {
        ReflectDir = VertexPosition;
    } else {
        vec3 worldPos = vec3( ModelMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition,1.0) );
        vec3 worldNorm = vec3(ModelMatrix * vec4(VertexNormal, 0.0));
        vec3 worldView = normalize( WorldCameraPosition - worldPos );

        ReflectDir = reflect(-worldView, worldNorm );
    }

    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(VertexPosition,1.0);
}
```

The fragment shader is here:

```
#version 430

in vec3 ReflectDir;

layout(binding=0) uniform samplerCube CubeMapTex;

uniform bool DrawSkyBox;
uniform float ReflectFactor;
uniform vec4 MaterialColor;

layout( location = 0 ) out vec4 FragColor;

void main() {
    // Access the cube map texture
    vec4 cubeMapColor = texture(CubeMapTex, ReflectDir);

    if( DrawSkyBox )
        FragColor = cubeMapColor;
    else
        FragColor = mix( MaterialColor, cubeMapColor, ReflectFactor);
}
```

So what I did to research the problem:

1) in the fragment shader I do not fetch the cubemap texture but set colors (within the if/else).
I clearly see the skybox in red and the teapot in green (in this test I still drew both) -> the draw calls and objects data are correct.

2) I tried with a "standard" 2D texure. I passed the standard texture coordinates and the fragment shader was simply fetching the texture (no if/else) -> working perfectly.

3) I found out that some drivers/APIs could transform the boolean to an int (it is probably an issue of old times but I removed this possibility as well):
I tried by sending an int and changing the condition to  if( DrawSkyBox > 0) { ... } and passing 1 to the uniform:

```
mProgram->setUniformValue("DrawSkyBox", 1);
```

even with typecast:

```
mProgram->setUniformValue("DrawSkyBox", (int) 1);
```

The shader was still executing the "else" part.

4) I moved the execution parts in specific functions, same result.

```
void CalcSkyBox()
{
    ReflectDir = VertexPosition;
}

void ObjReflect()
{
    vec3 worldPos  = vec3(ModelMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0));
    vec3 worldNorm = vec3(ModelMatrix * vec4(VertexNormal, 0.0));
    vec3 worldView = normalize(WorldCameraPosition - worldPos);

    ReflectDir = reflect(-worldView, worldNorm );    
}

void main()
{

    if (DrawSkyBox) {
        CalcSkyBox();
    } else {
        ObjReflect();
    }

    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

Why do I say it executes the "else" part since the beginning ? Well ...:

In the end I found out that by modifying "ReflectDir" in the else part of the vertex shader (-> `ReflectDir = reflect(-worldView, worldNorm );` replaced with  `ReflectDir = VertexPosition;`) then it works perfectly ! (I mean no crash and the skybox is displayed).

So I restate the question is: 
why is the shader executing the else part ?

Imarion

PS: it is a long read so thanks in advance if you reached this point and for any answer.

Comment: If by "*crash*" you mean "the application force closing" then whats found in the core dump, or the debugger of your IDE(if you use any)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit :). I use QT Creator. It sais "The application stopped working" so yes it is a kind of force closing. This is a segmentation fault at the draw call. (In my cpp: glDrawElements(...) -> In qopenglfunctions.h: d_ptr->DrawElements(mode, count, type, indices); Note that d_ptr is correctly initialisaed (DrawElements 0x58790c60 <glDrawElements> void (GLenum, GLsizei, GLenum, const GLvoid *)) Qt is quite in an unstable state, I can't get a core dump.

Comment: Made a new test, see 4 in my original message.

Answer (score 0):

Some GPUs may evaluate both sides of a branch and then discard one.  See: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter34.html

That doesn't explain why you would get a crash.  Could the vector you normalize be zero, so that normalization causes a divide by zero?

Comment: I supected some kind of optimisation. As for the normalisation, that is correct. I modified the calculation as such: ReflectDir = reflect(-worldView, vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)); and it does not crash. I will investigate more deeply later, I do not have time right now. Anyway thank you :) That said, it should not execute this part. There is this issue because for the Skybox those vectors are not passed ... They are not used.

Answer (score 0):

I created 2 programs to get rid of the "if" in the vertex shader.
I use the exact same fragment shader which has the "if".

Then everything works well.

I'm tempted to close this issue considering this is an optimisation bug from Nvidia vertex shader compiler.